# rosgraph: No definition of [python-netifaces] for OS [osx]

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosgraph, homebrew, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into some trouble while attempting a ros installation of groovy via Homebrew.  When trying to execute the following command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y
```

I continue seeing this issue:

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks
> could not have their rosdep keys
> resolved to system dependencies:
> rosgraph: No definition of
> [python-netifaces] for OS [osx]

I'm not sure how to proceed here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59113/rosgraph:-no-definition-of-%5Bpython-netifaces%5D-for-os-%5Bosx%5D/) by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I submitted a pull request on github to address the issue:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/597

As the error states, there was no definition in the homebrew yaml file for python-netifaces.  A new definition has been added called 'python-netifaces', which points to the netifaces pip.

---

Originally posted by [Yeison Rodriguez](https://answers.ros.org/users/4057/yeison-rodriguez/) with karma: 103 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-25**:
Thanks! That is the intended solution for problems like this one.